# Cocoa animationImages finish detection

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm doing an animation using animationImages and animationRepeatCount = 1;
How can I detect when the animation is done?

Thanks,
Tee

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't get a notification when UIImageView animations are finished. You should use NSObject's performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: method to schedule some code to execute after the time is done, but it won't be perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Set the [setAnimationDidStopSelector:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/setAnimationWillStartSelector:) to a method that takes action when the animation stops.

Comment: i think that is not the `UIImageView` animation - but the `UIView` animation.

Answer (score 1):

Very old question, but I needed a fix now, this works for me:

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
    DLog(@"Animation did finish.");
}];

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.window.bounds];
imageView.animationDuration = 0.3 * 4.0;
imageView.animationImages = @[[UIImage AHZImageNamed:@"Default2"],
                              [UIImage AHZImageNamed:@"Default3"],
                              [UIImage AHZImageNamed:@"Default4"],
                              [UIImage AHZImageNamed:@"Default5"]];
imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1;
[self.window addSubview:imageView];

[imageView startAnimating];

[CATransaction commit];
```